# What changes are needed for this conditional code to work on deeper levels?

Tags: conditional-tags

I use conditional code to apply a css highlight to the menu item of a page currently being viewed.

`<li<?php if ( is_page('channels') || '2704' == $post->post_parent ) {  echo " class=\"current\""; } // the page is 'channels', or the parent of the page is 'channels'?>><a href="/programs/channels/">Channels</a></li>`

I need to also apply it to all pages below that parent.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you were close.  Can you try reversing your post parent statement?

```
'2704' == $post->post_parent
```

should be

```
 ($post->post_parent == '2704')
```

Notice i put it in parentheses as well.

so your code would be:

```
    <li<?php if ( is_page('channels') || ($post->post_parent == '2704') ) { 
    echo " class=\"current\""; } // the page is 'channels', or the parent of the page is 'channels'?>>
<a href="/programs/channels/">Channels</a>
</li>
```

Comment: thanks. Didn't work. No worries, I found a solution and will update my post.

Comment: are you sure that is the correct post ID in your system?

Comment: yep, the ID seems ok.

Comment: `'2704' == $post->post_parent` is completely valid and identical to `$post->post_parent == '2704'`. In fact, [Yoda conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) are a good practice.

Comment: I know it will work. it's the parenthrses.  Also if one is learning.  it's better to ask  is parent equal 2704 rather than is 2704 equal to parent. not to mention it is better to stay consistent with the codex.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question...

Using is_tree seems to work.

Add this to functions:

```
function is_tree($pid)
{
global $post;
$ancestors = get_post_ancestors($post->$pid);
$root = count($ancestors) - 1;
$parent = $ancestors[$root];
if(is_page() && (is_page($pid) || $post->post_parent == $pid || in_array($pid, $ancestors)))
{
return true;
}
else
{
return false;
}
};
```

Usage is:

```
if (is_tree(POST ID HERE)) {
// 'POST ID HERE' is the post ID.
// do stuff
}
```

I've seen variants of is_tree, but I'm not smart enough to know if one is better than others.